# Android/Facebook: Posting an image from SD card on my Facebook's wall

Tags: android, facebook, sd-card

According to several searches I've made, here is what I have written in order to send an image I've just save on my SD card

```
    public void postToWall() throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    loginToFacebook();
    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        // Ok le login est bien enregistre
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message","test");
        File file = (File) this.getIntent().getExtras().get("PICTURE_TAKEN");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int data2 = 0;
            while ((data2 = fis.read()) != -1)
                baos.write(data2);
            fis.close();
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            bundle.putByteArray("Picture", bytes);
        mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", bundle, "POST", new FacebookPostListener(), null);
    }
}
```

I succeed in posting the text message "message" but not the image !
(the extra "PICTURE_TAKEN" being the File related to the picture taken)

Comment: i need your help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657388/how-to-allow-user-to-post-an-image-on-wall-using-sdcard-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've solved my problem
just replace "me/feed" by "photos"
in mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", bundle, "POST", new FacebookPostListener(), null);

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting a new project, you should use [version 3.0 of the Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) where posting a photo is very easy: see [Request.newUploadPhotoRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newUploadPhotoRequest%28Session,%20File,%20Callback%29).