# How to allow user to post an Image on Wall using SDCard Folder

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am allowing user to *post a message on their [Friend & User] Wall* along *with single static image*, and for that image i am using *Web Image URL*

But now i wish to *allow user to choose any single image from multiple images*, like 10 images stored in a particular folder in **SDCard**, and then *post to Wall*.

*So here is my question, how to do that?*

My existing code to **post static image on Wall**, read below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("to", String.valueOf(friendId));
        params.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));
        params.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
        params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
            params.putString("picture",FacebookUtility.HACK_ICON_URL);
            params.putString("name",getString(R.string.app_action));

            FacebookUtility.facebook.dialog(FriendsList.this,
           "feed", params, (DialogListener) new PostDialogListener());
      }
  }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();
 } catch (JSONException e) {
      showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**FacebookUtility.java:-**

```
public static final String HACK_ICON_URL = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-WuasmTMjMA4/TY0SS4TzIMI/AAAAAAAAFB4/6alyfOzWsqM/s320/flowers-wallpapers-love-blooms-roses-bunch-of-flowers.jpg";
```

*Check existing screen of my app,*

[image]

*As you can see in above screen i am showing only single static image as i have written above, but now i wanna allow user to choose an image from multiple images using SD Card, my SDCard path* like: **/sdcard/FbImages/**

***now i want to know how to place button in above screen [because i am not using any custom xml for this, that's native feature in FacebookSDK]***

So here is my question *how to open sdcard folder and how to choose single image to post from multiple images*

Comment: Please check my answer below. The screen Shot which you have upload its of the app Request. So, can only able to change it if other all images have their own url.

Answer (score 1):

you have to find path for that image.

try following code to select image

```
btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setType("image/*");
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 0);
        }
    });
```

get path for selectd image

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);

        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

then use

```
  params.putString("picture",selectedImagePath);
```

Comment: bro please come here, i need support

Comment: hi actually i am not getting how to use your code in mine, i have also uploaded screen shot of my app, now i want to know how to place button in above screen to open sdcard folder and how to choose one to post from multiple images

Comment: just put button anywhere in your activity and select image(get path) by onclick() before displaying facebook dialog.

Comment: where you want to do facebook stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for notifying me to the answer here. As you have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585043/android-how-to-post-the-message-with-the-image-post-on-facebook?), I am sending app request to my Facebook friend. However its nothing like to post photo on Friend's wall. There you only able to post App icon with the url ASK.

If you want to post photo on Friends wall with message then please check my below answer.

```
Bundle param = new Bundle();
param.putString("message", "picture caption");
param.putByteArray("picture", ImageBytes);
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());
```

In my above code, ImageBytes is the byte[] of the Image. You will have to play little to select image from the particular folder then convert that selected image in to byte[]. Use that byte[] in my above code.

Comment: thanks for help, but i not getting how to allow user to pick a single image from multiple in my screen, that's the main question

Comment: Do you want to have images from gallery then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use it when pick bitmap from sdcard and give the path also past this code.

```
protected void share(String nameApp, String imagePath, String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager()
                    .queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                    Intent targetedShare = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime
                    // type
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(
                            nameApp)
                            || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(
                                    nameApp)) {
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                        targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```